# How to initialize Tooltips in MDL-Stepper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make an MDL-Stepper, which is working nice, but I'm really struggling with getting tooltips to work there.

On other pages at my Website I'm using this javascript:

```
     function ($scope, $timeout, bsLoadingOverlayService){

        var initialize = function () {
                //moreFunctions
                $scope.initTooltips();
            }

         $scope.initTooltips = function () {
            angular.element(".tooltipped").tooltip();
        }

       initialize();
    });
```

and in HTML:

```
<a class="btn right tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50"
                                   data-tooltip="TooltipText" 
                           >ButtonText</a>
```

All of this is working great, but when using the MDL-stepper the tooltips won't appear.
My Stepper looks like this:

```
<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

                            <div class="mdl-stepper-horizontal-alternative">
                                <div class="mdl-stepper-step" ng-class="{'editable-step': isStepDone(1) && !isStepActive(1), 'active-step' : isStepDone(1) || isStepActive(1)}" ng-click="stepTo(1)">
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-circle"><span>1</span></div>
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-title">StepOne</div>
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-left"></div>
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-right"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mdl-stepper-step" ng-class="{'editable-step': isStepDone(2) && !isStepActive(2), 'active-step' : isStepDone(2) || isStepActive(2)}" ng-click="stepTo(2)">
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-circle"><span>2</span></div>
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-title">StepTwo</div>
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-left"></div>
                                    <div class="mdl-stepper-bar-right"></div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
</div>
```

I tried to init the tooltips in the initialize function and in the stepTo(..) function, but it didn't work.

Comment: what's an `mdl-stepper`? You failed to mention any libraries, plugins or frameworks being used other than angular and jQuery